# Check the content in ajax call

Tags: jquery

Is it possbile to check whether the content is loaded fully in the ajax call made and after that show some div. Till the content is not loaded fully the div should not shown and after the content is come then the div has to be shown using jquery?

Comment: What do you mean by "the content is fully loaded"? What is the content? Every Ajax method accepts a success callback which is executed once the response was received.

Comment: @Felix I have image to content and images to load in ajax. I am calculation the height of the div and when the full content has come, i what a div to show. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

the answer is based on total assumptions, also define an error callback

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/path/to/server",
  type: 'POST',
  data: data,
  success: function(data){    <-- the success is called upon successful completion    
    //do something with data
   $("#divID").html(data);
   $("#divID").show();  <-- assumed the div was hidden initially
  },
  error:function(jxhr){
   if(typeof(console)!='undefined'){
    console.log(jxhr.status+"--"+jxhr.responseText);
   }
 }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [jQuery ajax call success callback](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). It will fires only after finishing the request:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "some.html",
   success: function(data){
     // show my div here
     $('#mydivid').html(data).show();
   }
 });
```